# How to make a compressed file with unique extension name, containing many files

Tags: c#, file, encryption, compression

I used to work for a company that used 3dxml files. I learned that a 3dxml file is just a compressed collection of other files.  If you change the extension to "zip," you can manually decompress the collection.

I'm currently programming something for a new project, and I want to make a single unique file extension that contains all my output files.

My questions:  What is the workflow for making a compressed unique file format?  Are the files written normally, and some method "compresses" the items into a single file, that zip file is renamed to the unique extension, and the original files are deleted?  Or are there programming methods that allow someone to write the files in the encryption directly, so that you don't have to do the step above?

Comment: Have you looked at System.IO.Packaging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging). There are lots of file formats that are collections of XML files zipped together (like the Office formats, .xlsx, .doc, etc)

Comment: Is your question 'how do I create a zip file'? Or 'how do I create a 3dxml file?' Or something else?

Comment: `in the encryption` What do you mean by `in the encryption`?

Comment: I haven't looked at system.io.packaging, because I'm posting this question because I don't know where to begin.  I'm basically asking what is the workflow for exporting a custom file format that contains separate files. Is it by making the files and compressing them, or is there a programmatic way to write all the files in the compressed format?

Comment: Thanks to @Flydog57's link, I think i might have found what I'm looking for:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.package?view=netframework-4.8  I'm just skimming it, but it looks kind of like it will help me read and write "packages" that contain different file types.

Comment: This looks like the way to "get the parts" of the package:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.package.getparts?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Packaging_Package_GetParts

Comment: Most of the time (since think twice before building a compression algorithm and related managing system from scratch), people just change the extension. You can register the extension with the Shell, so existing compressors won't know the file can be opened. Compressor that take a closer look into the format, do know (as 7Zip). So, sometime people also change the first 3-7 bytes  of the file, so nothing can open it. You can restore the original bytes when you open the archive, then use the original compressor/packager. This *technique* might be seen as a patent violation.